# How do you open a .pkd (Quanvert) file in R

Tags: r

I have been asked to open a .pkd (Quanvert) file in R but cannot seem to find any documentation on how to do this. Can someone please help

Comment: Just a complete stab in the dark - did you try the `read.spss` function in the `foreign` package? No idea if it would work because I don't know SPSS functionality but worth a shot. (And if it doesn't work - do you really need to open this file directly in R? Or would it work to export it to some other format first, like txt?)